# Instalar proyecto existente de laravel

Tags: php, laravel, github

Hola que tal? quiero instalar un proyecto de laravel descargado de github, en mi xampp, localhost. Pero tengo el error que aparece en la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos y bienvenido recomiendo leer [ask], mi primer consejo copia y pega el código en tu pregunta para que sea mas legible, dale clic en editar a tu pregunta y pégalo; posterior seleccionalo y dale click al ícono {} que le va a dar formato

Comment: El problema entonces era que no habias configurado bien el .env?

Comment: Si. ademas aprendí que puedo descargar una version de phar para cualquier proyecto.Solo debo colocar el archivo dentro de mi proyecto, y ejecutar los comandos de composer. En otro caso hice una pregunta de configuración de variable COMPOSER. Y resolví ejecutando mi proyecto con el archivo phar descargado de la pagina de composer.

Answer (score 1):

cada vez que descargues un proyecto nuevo de laravel te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1. ejecutar composer install
2. Dentro del directorio crear el archivo .env  y agregar las credenciales de tu base de datos.
3. php artisan cache:clear y php artisan config:cache
4. php artisan serve

esto debiera funcionar, saludos

Comment: gracias saludos

Comment: Tu ve que editar esto comentarios por que me equivoque de post jajaja..  Gracias saludos! El problema era que no habia configurado bien el .env